# Backbone.js render a view with a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asynchronous, requirejs, backbone.js-collections

I'm n00b with Backbone/Require JS and I'm trying to run a View based in a Collection.
I've split the code in files following MVC pattern
This is my code for the view:

File: views/petDirectory

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'models/pet',
  'collections/pets',
  'text!templates/pet/directory.html'
], function($, Backbone, PetModel, PetsCollection, petDirectoryTemplate){

var PetDirectoryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#main"),
    template: _.template(petDirectoryTemplate),
    collection: new PetsCollection(),

    initialize: function() {
        var view = this;
        view.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var view = this;
        var compiledTemplate = this.template({pets: view.collection});
        view.$el.html( compiledTemplate );
        return this;
    },
});

return PetDirectoryView;
});
```

Data is loaded via API RESTful in the models, and I create the instance of PetDirectoryView in router.js.

But I'm having something wrong (maybe asynchronus calls) because my template doesn't show the items and my Chrome Console shows something like this:

```
r {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, url: "http://localhost:3000/pets"…}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm writing the question I've the answer! Thanks StackOverflow! :D

The point is don't render the view before ends the callback function in fetch().
The code is above:

```
initialize: function() {
        var view = this;
        view.collection = new PetsCollection();
        view.collection.fetch({
            success: function(){
                view.render();
            }
        });
        console.log(view.collection);
        view.render();
},
render: function() { ... }
```